# unable to save decimal value in decimal type in pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, rdd

I'm trying to write a json into a dataframe using pyspark. json has a decimal value and in the schema also I have defined that field as DecimalType but when creating the data frame, spark throws exception that **TypeError: field pr: DecimalType(3,1) can not accept object 20.0 in type**

`r = {'name':'wellreading','pr':20.0}
distData = sc.parallelize([r])
schema = StructType([StructField('name',StringType(),True),StructField('pr',DecimalType(3,1),True)])
df = spark.createDataFrame(distData,schema)
df.collect()`

here I have given a sample code but I'm unable to understand how come spark determines that 20.0 is float and can not be stored in decimal type?

Answer (score 0):

One of the quick solutions (not sure if the best one) is that you can read your json file directly to a data frame and then perform a conversion you like, eg.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import DecimalType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df1 = spark.read.json("/tmp/test.json")

df2 = df1.select(col('name'),col('pr').cast(DecimalType(3,1)).alias('pr'))
df2.printSchema()

root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- pr: decimal(3,1) (nullable = true)
```

OR

```
df2 = df1.withColumn("pr",df1.pr.cast(DecimalType(3,1)))
```